# Saving image to Photo Library and get the URL of the saved image

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary

I'm trying to save an image from camera to Photo Library and then store the URL of the saved image. My code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc]init];
[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:(__bridge CGImageRef)([info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage])
                          orientation:ALAssetOrientationUp completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
                              if(error == nil) {
                                  _myImageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",assetURL];
                                  NSLog(@"%@",assetURL);
                              } else NSLog(@"%@",error);
                          }];

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];}
```

My problem is that assetUrl is always NULL. Any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: It might be related to this post. Could be an iOS7 bug.

[ALAssetsLibraryWriteVideoCompletionBlock return undefined values][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813540/alassetslibrarywritevideocompletionblock-return-undefined-values

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after reading more, I found out the answer: the first parameter of the function is of `CGImageRef` type and `(__bridge CGImageRef)` doesn't do what I expected; but if I call the `CGImage` method of `UIImage` object, it works. The correct way to do this is:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc]init];
    CGImageRef image = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] CGImage];
    [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:image
                              orientation:ALAssetOrientationUp
                          completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
                                  if(error == nil) {
                                      _myImageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",assetURL];
                                      NSLog(@"%@",assetURL);
                                  } else NSLog(@"%@",error);
                              }];

    self.toDoImage.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```